# Universal links: working without backend

Tags: ios, url-scheme, ios-universal-links

Let's see on next example.
I have simple application - Notes manager. You can create notes like in native iOS application. For this application I no need backend at all. Just create/edit/remove note. And I have this app on iOS and Android. Now I need implement sharing note through applications. So, I have next flow:
when you share note from iOS app - creating link like "http://MyNoteApp/newNote/hello+world!" and sending on email. Another user open this email on Android device, tap on link, launch application an automatically create new note "hello world".
And from iOS to Android it works well! Now I need do it vise versa.
I read about [universal links](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html?utm_source=revxblog) , seems like it exactly what I need. But, it needs backend (unlike me). And I  haven't found info about this. Can someone helps me find workaround about it ? Or maybe I need another mechanism like url-scheme?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use another mechanism: you can configure a custom URL scheme for your app (both iOS and Android), something like `mynotes://`; all links with this scheme opened on the device will trigger your app and you can extract the note text from the URL parameter.

Comment: thanks, i will try. Problem that Android application was developed earlier and already using current scheme. (http://MyNotesApp/). So desired requirement is using current style...